# Is there a defined strategy for versioning SignalR hubs, so that old JS code can continue to work?

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr, versioning, api-design

I want to be able to make changes to the method signatures, names, etc on existing SignalR hubs. Is there a defined strategy for versioning SignalR hubs, so that old JS code can continue to work, without having to create a fresh newly named hub for the new calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say the short answer is no. Signalr does not have any versioning strategy like that.

The question is a little light on details, but signalr has for instance the option to use an attribute on a class to define the hubname. You could also create a new hub class by deriving from the original Hub in order to help you reuse existing code. Whatever you do new clientside js will need to be written.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change  method name and expect the Javascript to understand you changed it's name.
As for the method signatures -  Javascript isn't a strongly typed programming languages , so you can pass to the hub diffrent kinds of variables(as long as the number of the variables stays the same) .

However, you can create new methods, if you want to still support the old ones.

Comment: There should be a way to ship a version number to the server though and route to the appropriate hub.